# Can we assign a keyboard shortcut to a particular window in Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I have so many apps to work with, and each has som many windows. Is thre a way to assign key windows with a keyboard shortcut (not apps). So Window 1 of Excel with F1 for example.

OR

Is there a program that can manage this. For eg. I can tag, out of 30 windows on my computer, 3 key ones that I use very frequently, more so than the rest. Then instead of Cmd+Tab to go one by one to the app in question, and then after that *still* go thru window by window to the approrpaite one, can I just have, when I press say F1, the program appearing showing the 3 windows I have marked as important, choose the approrpiate one, and voila.

Comment: Thought I should bring up the Cmd+Backtick shortcut, which allows instant transition between various windows of a single application. This doesn't answer the question, but may help. If I find some time later this afternoon, I will try to see if I can find a solution for your original question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two programs that could help you: [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) and [Optimal layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/).

Also, you can choose a keyboard shortcut in the system preferences to activate application windows: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch apps, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓ (down arrow)</kbd> (for me) to switch between windows.

And if you don't mind using Expose, you may check the "Group windows by applications" checkbox in the Mission control panel of the system preferences.

Comment: Thanks @G-Man for your edit, I was looking for the kbd formating and didn't found it.